# How to host Angular App and .NET Core API on same domain

Tags: angular, apache, .net-core

I published my .NET Core API application and uploaded it to **/var/www/vhosts/domainname.com/httpdocs** with Plesk Panel's File Manager. I created a folder named **ClientApp** in the same directory and uploaded my **Angular** application into it.

My server is **Ubuntu Linux** and I added my .NET Core application as a service. It currently appears to be running on **http://localhost:5000**.

But when I go to **[www.domainname.com](http://www.domainname.com)**, I cannot see my API page.
I am faced with this screen.

```
"Server Error 403 Forbidden - You do not have permission to access this document."
```

I know that this is because there is no index file.

When I try to go to **[www.domainname.com/ClientApp](http://www.domainname.com/ClientApp)**, a blank white page appears.

**I want to ask here is:**

- what should I enter as apiUrl in the environment.ts file of my Angular application?
  this is current environment.ts file:

```
export const environment = {
  production: false,
  apiUrl: 'https://localhost:5000/',
  allowFileExtension: ['pdf', 'doc', 'docx', 'xls', 'xlsx'],
  allowExtesions: ['pdf', 'doc', 'docx'],
  maximumFileSize: 104857600
};
```

- What do I need to do to verify that my .NET Core application is running smoothly and that I can access it from my domain?
- How should Apache proxy configuration be?

this is .NET Core App launchSettings.json

```
{
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iis": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost/PROJECT.API",
      "sslPort": 0
    },
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:30634",
      "sslPort": 44346
    }
  },
  "$schema": "http://json.schemastore.org/launchsettings.json",
  "profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "swagger",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      },
      "ancmHostingModel": "InProcess"
    },
    "Docker": {
      "commandName": "Docker",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "{Scheme}://{ServiceHost}:{ServicePort}/swagger",
      "publishAllPorts": true,
      "useSSL": true
    },
    "IIS": {
      "commandName": "IIS",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

When I run the same project on my localhost, the URL that comes up when the API application is opened is as follows:
https://localhost:44346/swagger/index.html

I can send requests to the API endpoints of my application running on localhost using Postman as follows:
https://localhost:44346/api/Authentication